# Should git checkout bypass index and only update working tree?

Tags: git

From [the Atlassian docs](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/resetting-checking-out-and-reverting):

> #### Git Checkout File
>
> Checking out a file is similar to using `git reset` with a file path, 
>   except it updates the *working directory**  instead of
>   the stage. Unlike the commit-level version of this command, this does
>   not move the HEAD reference, which means that you won’t switch
>   branches.

And a bit farther down:

> If you *stage*** and commit the checked-out file, this has the effect of “reverting” to the old version of that file.

However when I `git checkout <sha1> -- <file>` I see the change added to both my working tree (ie, the file in sublime updates) *and* `git status` shows the modification to the file is green and in staged/in-index. (Verified by `git diff` giving empty output.)

### Is my git misconfigured, are their docs incorrect, or have I misunderstood them?

<sub>*their emphasis</sub>

<sub>**my emphasis</sub>

Comment: You better search the information at the source: the official [documentation page of `git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout).

Comment: @axiac So the Atlassian docs are incorrect it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Atlassian document is completely wrong here.

`git checkout tree-ish -- path` copies the specified *`path`* first to your index (aka staging-area), then from your index to your work-tree.  This *overwrites* whatever was in the index before.  The *`tree-ish`* here is how the Git documentation means to tell you that anything that will find a commit or a commit's tree object suffices.  Mostly people use commit hash IDs, branch names, and relative names like `HEAD~3` here, but anything from [the gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) suffices.

(To check out a commit, the `checkout` code needs a commit hash, in which case only a commit ID will do.  For this particular case, though, it only needs to find the source tree snapshot *associated with* the commit ID.  Git can use the commit to find the tree just like it does for a commit checkout, but you can supply the tree hash ID itself directly.  There's almost never a reason for a human to do this, but some software might want to.  See also [the `git rev-parse` documentation](https://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html).)

Note, however, that `git checkout -- path` copies from your index to your work-tree (without first extracting from *`tree-ish`* to index).  This can lead to the wrong assumption that they made.

There *is* a way to extract a file directly from a commit to your work-tree, without first going through your index, using `git show` or `git cat-file -p`.  In older versions of Git this process *always* skips any end-of-line and other filter and text-conversion items, which `git checkout` does for you normally; in newer Gits, you can force these conversions to occur the way they would with `git checkout`.  This caveat only matters if you are using *smudge filters*, the `ident` filter, or CRLF line-ending conversion options.

Comment: What does `-ish` (`commit-ish`) mean in this context?

Comment: I really should have said `tree-ish` (will fix). But: where the documentation uses "commit-ish", you can supply: a raw hash ID; a branch name; a tag name; a relative commit identifier like `HEAD~3`; or any of the other fancy items listed in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).

Comment: And `tree-ish` and `commit-ish` in the way you are using them mean exactly the same thing, eg `a raw hash ID; a branch name; a tag name; a relative commit identifier like HEAD~3; or any of the other fancy items listed in the gitrevisions documentation` ?

Comment: In this case, yes. I added an expansion and parenthetical paragraph on this.

Comment: The last paragraph here seems like a little bit of a diversion from the main answer. I say so because it's piqued my curiosity and I intend to read up on it and it may eventually lead to a question of its own. Thanks for the nice writeup. Cheers.

Comment: It *is* a diversion from the main answer :-) but if someone stumbles over the question because that's what they *want* to do—to extract a file from some other commit without disturbing a staged copy—it seems like it should be in there.